# Selenium2 phpunit: How to run tests on Opera browser (new one like chrome)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit, opera, selenium-grid

My tests working normally on other browsers (Safari, Chrome, FF ...) but I cant do it on Opera. Im using grid, this is my node:

```
java -jar C:\Users\netr\Desktop\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar 
     -role node -port 5222 -hub http://ip:4444/grid/register -maxSession 5 
     -browser "browserName=opera,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS,
               opera_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe"
```

When I'm staring my cases the Opera browser opens and loaded this URL `http://127.0.0.1:12486`
for every case the port is different. Then there is the error:

> Could not start Opera: launcher unable to start binary

I tried to change path to the binary (opera.exe or to launcher.exe) but still I cant to open my URL from the cases.

My Versions:

- Opera version is 17.0.1241.53 - Opera is up to date
- PHPUnit 3.7.24 by Sebastian Bergmann.
- PHPUnit_Selenium 1.3.1 (stable)

Answer (score 0):

There is a note on OperaDriver info page http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver:

> Current implementation of OperaDriver supports only 12.x and older versions of Opera browser (based on Presto engine) and does not support newer versions (based on Blink engine).

So the only solution seems to be waiting for ChromeDriver developers to fix this issue or use the 12.x version of Opera.